# POI,JAVA: Got an "Unexpected ptg class" error when trying to evaluate a cell formula with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I have a tiny tool which is using Apache POI 3.17 to read excel files. But the tool is not working with excel files which some of their cells have a LOOKUP formula, like this:

> LOOKUP(B2,{"APPLE","ORANGE","GRAPE","BANANA","MANGO"},{1,2,3,4,5})

<del>I just want to get a String value of the formula cell. How can I solve this problem?</del>

Edit:
I just want to get a formula result of the cell. How can I solve this problem?

My code:

```
File file = new File("D:/temp/spec.xls");
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("sheet1");
CellReference cellRef = new CellReference("B3");
HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(cellRef.getRow()).getCell(cellRef.getCol());

HSSFFormulaEvaluator formulaEval = 
workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
HSSFDataFormatter dataFormatter = new HSSFDataFormatter();

System.out.println(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEval));
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected ptg class (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.ArrayPtg)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.getEvalForPtg(WorkbookEvaluator.java:682)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:516)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:278)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:220)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:200)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellEnum(BaseFormulaEvaluator.java:192)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.formatCellValue(DataFormatter.java:986)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.formatCellValue(DataFormatter.java:944)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter$formatCellValue$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at ideaGroovyConsole.run(ideaGroovyConsole.groovy:19)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:263)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:518)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:497)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:169)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at console.run(console.txt:25)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processReader(GroovyMain.java:631)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processFiles(GroovyMain.java:539)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:382)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:370)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:129)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:109)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:131)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:65)
```

Comment: Get the cell content without the formulaEval.

Comment: @XavierBouclet Thank you!  But maybe I'm not saying it clearly. I need to get the formula result not the formula itself. I have to use the formulaEval to calculate the formula, right? Would you mind to be more specific about getting the cell content without the formulaEval?

Comment: Does the cell evaluate in ms Excel?

Comment: And try evaluate without referencing B2 but with B2 content directly in B3. Poi doesn’t evaluate B2 in B3.

Comment: @XavierBouclet But B2 content varies in different excel files so it's necessary to reference B2. If POI doesn’t evaluate B2 in B3, does that mean we don't have a solution currently? I found a post [here](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Advice-on-tracking-down-an-error-thrown-by-evaluateAllFormulaCells-td5721053.html) with same exceptions, seems POI doesn't supports the formula for now.

Comment: I said try the formula without referencing B2 only for test purpose. Put the B2 content directly in B3. It’s sure Poi doesn’t fully support formula. Some formula are supported. I saw a post where referencing another cell was the pb. Worth to try.

Comment: @XavierBouclet Not working with or without the referencing.